# Change the height of a movieclip from a registration point

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is there a way to extend only the bottom part of a dynamic Movieclip? I tried to change the height or to scale my mc but it always makes the change relativity to the center of the Movieclip. I guess I should define a registration point and change the height according to it but i'm not sure of how to do it. Hope someone can guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.flashwonderland.com/transformation-matrix/transformation-matrix-2.html

You can use matrix transforms to achieve that effect.

for a scale from the top use something like this:

```
var scaleFromTopY:Number = 2;// change this to the correct number.
var scaleFromTopX:Number = 1;// change this as well

var topScaleMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix(
        scaleFromTopX, 0,
        0, scaleFromTopY,
        0, (mc.height*scaleFromTopY)/2 // Make this last part into -(mc.height*scaleFromTopY)/2 to scale from the bottom
);
mc.transform.matrix = topScaleMatrix;
```

You can also combine matrices with `Matrix.concat(m:Matrix);`

Comment: It works very nice and I learned something new, thanks mate :)

Comment: no problem, you can do a lot of other cool stuff with matrices. I suggest you learn how to use them. They can make some pretty cool actionscript based animations

Answer (score 0):

In Flash the registration point can never be changed, to get around this, you must position all the child elements where you want them in relation to the (0,0) point. All transformations will happen around this (0,0) point no matter where the content is placed inside the DisplayObject.

Comment: This is actually incorrect, if you use matrices you can achieve just about any transformation

Comment: This is true, but does not make my answer incorrect! Matrix transformations can be confusing to someone who doesn't even know the basics of Flash yet, so I gave a simple version.

Comment: You can't change the registration point at runtime, but you can in the Flash IDE