# How to scale object in Flash/Actionscript so that an object doesn't get shifted to the middle?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm noob, playing around with Flash, and trying to squeeze an object in Actionscript1, changing _xscale or _width. But unexpectedly, although _x coordinate is set constant, the image gets shifted:

[image]

Here grey cloud represents object before scale, white cloud - after scale.

My question is why that happens and how do I stick an object to a certain point, so that upon scaling it stay attached to it (e.g. I want position of upper-left or upper-right corner fixed)?

UPDATE: Is my opinion of how transformation works correct:

Changing _xscale doesn't decrease the size, allotted for the image and doesn't snap image to its _x, _y, but instead keeps resized image at the center of the initial image's center?

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the image in the ide, or is it loaded dynamically from another source? If in the IDE you can set the scale point on the far left of the MC and then when you scale it will scale from that point instead of from the center.

Comment: @Avik "it will scale from that point instead of from the center" - so the image scales from the center and pads the emerging vacant space between axes and rescaled image? I'm doing it in old Flash MX. Also, what is MC? What's the name of that point I should drag? Is it transformation point or registration point or something else? In fact, I've just loaded image from Photoshop and want to transform it programmatically with Actionscript.

Comment: I believe it's called the registration point.  By changing the registration point, you change where it scales from. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692577/change-the-height-of-a-movieclip-from-a-registration-point

Comment: Although one of those answers says you can't change registration points. That's not true in the IDE. You can click on the registration point and move it to anywhere else.  MC stands for "MovieClip"

Comment: @Avik Thanks a lot, Avik, seems, that question suggests the approach, I have to use!

Comment: should we close this as a duplicate of that question or are you looking for an answer to something else as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use transformation matrix, so you want a scale and then a translate. So with transformation matrix you resolve then in the inverse, so you would translate then scale.

If you want you have the left side of your smaller cloud to be at the exact same position as the old could. Move it to the left for 1/4 of the original could's width. Then scale it by 1/2 and it should give you what you want.